# Sequence doesn't converge

Tags: real-analysis

I want to brush up on my analysis skills, and I found a good practice exercise. I'm trying to show that for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the sequence $x_n = Ax_{n-1}$ does not converge, where $A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \cos \theta & \sin \theta \end{bmatrix}$ for some $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$. I think it suffices to fix $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$ and show that for all $N$, there exists $n, m > N$ such that $\lvert\lvert x_{n} - x_{m}\rvert\rvert_2 > 1$. But I'm stuck because I don't see a clear relationship between $n$ and $m$ that would cause these $x_n$ and $x_m$ to be far enough away from each other.

Here's my attempt at the problem: From the way the recurrence is defined, I think $x_n = A^{n}x_0$. So, it suffices to show that $\lvert\lvert A^{n}x_{0} - A^{m}x_{0}\rvert\rvert_2 > 1$. One thought I had was to show that a lower bound for $\lvert\lvert A^{n}x_{0} - A^{m}x_{0}\rvert\rvert_2$ still exceeds 1. I try this below, but I don't think I'm going in the right direction.

$$\begin{align*}
\lvert\lvert A^{n}x_{0} - A^{m}x_{0}\rvert\rvert_2 &\geq \lvert \left(\lvert\lvert A^{n}x_0\rvert\rvert_2 - \lvert\lvert A^{m}x_0\rvert\rvert_2\right)\rvert \\
&\geq \lvert\lvert A^{n}x_0\rvert\rvert_2 - \lvert\lvert A^{m}x_0\rvert\rvert_2 \\
&\geq \lvert\lvert A^{n}x_0\rvert\rvert_2 - \lvert\lvert A^{m}\rvert\rvert_F \lvert \lvert x \rvert\rvert_2 \\
&\geq \lvert\lvert A^{n}x_0\rvert\rvert_2 - (\lvert\lvert A\rvert\rvert_F)^m \lvert \lvert x \rvert\rvert_2 \\
&= \lvert\lvert A^{n}x_0\rvert\rvert_2 - (\sqrt{2})^m \lvert \lvert x \rvert\rvert_2 \\
\end{align*}
$$ .

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The statement is false. If $x_0=(0,0)$, then every $x_n$ is equal to $(0,0)$, and so the sequence converges.

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps the exercise forgot to qualify the statement to avoid this case. I assume the statement is true for $x_0 \neq (0, 0)$?

Comment: No, it is not enough. If $x_0=(1,0)$ and $\theta=\frac\pi2$, then $n>0\implies x_n=(0,0)$.

Comment: Check whether you copied the formula for $A(\theta)$ correctly.

Comment: I copied it correctly. I'm looking into seeing if a correction has been made available. 
Thank you everyone!

Comment: @bandicoot12 the matrix you are dealing with is a rotation, you should see what's happening when writing your problem with complex notations.

Comment: The bottom left entry should've been $\sin \theta$. Seeing this matrix as a rotation (as @blamethelag pointed out) makes the problem a lot more clear!